# JS: IF url from address equals, post to MULTIPLE divs

Tags: javascript, url, html

Me again, back with some fire for an actual question (so I wont get flamed again). I just posted an abstract concept of what I needed and I had some GREAT and immediate help. Now, Its time to boil this down.

This code works, however, **it does not work for multiple pages**, and I am unsure why.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if(url == "http://www.promilitarybusinessnetwork.com/continueSearch.asp?categoryID=108") {
        $('#website').html('<p>This is the Apartments Category page</p>');
    } else {
        $('#website').empty();
    }});

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if(url == "http://www.promilitarybusinessnetwork.com/continueSearch.asp?categoryID=13") {
        $('#website').html('<p>This is the Business Category page</p>');
    } else {
        $('#website').empty();
    }});
```

The code above does not work when multiple instances occur. So if i removed the BUSINESS category code, and just left the APARTMENTS category, Apartments will work. Vice versa for the business code.

**As it stands, when i leave both of them up, as seen above, the BUSINESS category is the only one that shows.**

You can see what Im trying to accomplish here:

http://www.promilitarybusinessnetwork.com/

Im working on revising and updating this site, which i took over. The "container" is solid, along with the header, but the pages need help. This is what Im trying to do, but I need to get this working 100% before I can style it out in depth. Website is using ASP, so its tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `if`/`else if`/`else`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (url === "http://www.promilitarybusinessnetwork.com/continueSearch.asp?categoryID=108") {
        $("#website").html("<p>This is the Apartments Category page</p>");
    } else if (url === "http://www.promilitarybusinessnetwork.com/continueSearch.asp?categoryID=13") {
        $("#website").html("<p>This is the Business Category page</p>");
    } else {
        $("#website").empty();
    }
});
```

This makes each option mutually exclusive. If one of them is `true`, it executes, but none of the others do.

Comment: Yes, YOU sir, are the man. This worked perfectly. I knew it was something this simple, but i cant write javascript just yet. Learning, though!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @FlannelBeard Haha no problem. Glad it was definitely the solution! Keep working on it, you're learning :)

Comment: My last post I had NO clue what to do to get the URL to function. Some good people helped, but i got flamed for writing "if url = (url), then write to dive (#div) = ('this is the ___ category), so I got a LONG ways to go but each bit helps! Thanks again :D